# Laravel - Download a view to the users computer as a PDF

Tags: pdf, laravel-4

Have a view that works as I intend, but instead of the user clicking a button and the return being a view, I want instead download a PDF of that view.

So instead of the user getting the view response, then clicking save and download as PDF, it does it all in one.

Anything already built into Laravel for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dompdf` for this purpose. Its very easy to use. Github link below

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf